# not able to run a bat or exe file using wine

Tags: python, wine

I downloaded a RVC voice conversion model in my ubuntu 20.04 system, in that i need to run a .bat file, i tried to run it by using wine(version 8.0.2), but its giving an error.
the .bat file contains the code "runtime\python.exe infer-web.py --pycmd runtime\python.exe --port 7897".
The error is:
"The program python.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close, we are sorry for the inconvenience.This can be caused by the program or a deficiency in wine. you may want to check the Application Database( this is the link for this: https://appdb.winehq.org/) for tips about running this application."

please someone tell me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: As the project seems to use Python, it should run cross-plattform, unless they use very specific Windows modules. You may want to check on the project page whether they offer other downloads, e.g. the Python source code.

Answer (score 0):

Given the command, I will suppose you are using this: https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI/

So, **Did you install "Python for Windows" in Wine?** if you didn't you can try doing that first and check if it works. According to the Wine HQ Database, [it should work](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=7578)

However, **as it's using Python, it should also run directly in Ubuntu** or any other Linux distribution **without using Wine**, you can just execute the `run.sh` which comes with the package, take a look to it [here](https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI/blob/main/run.sh).

If you still need by any chance one of the commands in the bat files, you can just copy them, remove the `runtime` and the `.exe` parts, change the `--pycmd` parameter to `python3` and run them directly in Ubuntu. So, for the command you provided, it will look something like:

```
python infer-web.py --pycmd python3 --port 7897
```